# Speed up Get-ADUser in a 100k user company, without knowing ntids or emails beforehand. Split and process in parallel?

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, active-directory

I am calculating password expiration dates from the active directory, every ten minutes, for the entire company. The company's list of employees changes everyday, so I cannot have a static list and `-LdapFilter` against it. The below powershell script takes about 4.30 minutes to complete on a Windows Server 2016 Dual Core VM that is connected directly to the company's network:

```
$outputFile = ".\AD_PW_Expiration.csv"
$domains = @("a","b","c")
foreach ($domain in $domains) {
     Get-ADUser -server "$domain.company.com" -LdapFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(mail=*)(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))" -SearchBase "OU=User,OU=Accounts,DC=$domain,dc=company,dc=com" -SearchScope subtree `
       -Properties SAMAccountName,canonicalName,displayName,mail,msds-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | `
       Select @{n="Domain";e={$_.CanonicalName.Split('/')[0]}},SAMAccountName,displayName,mail,@{Name="PasswordExpires";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}} | `
       Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation $outputfile -Append
}
```

I want to bring down the speed many folds, less than 10 seconds. An idea that I have is to split the user list to chunks and run the script for each independent chunk, in parallel. If I go with this approach, can I split the employees without knowing beforehand their ntids/emails? Is there a way maybe through LdapFilter to do ranges (from nth user until (n+m) user)?

Comment: How long does it take to only get the user entries from AD (without piping the output and export as csv ? I don't know much about powershell but the bottleneck could be that the output processing takes longer than retrieving the entries. In this case you can think of using pagination control (which only allows to get paged results _sequentially_, it would be too simple otherwise..) and export data asynchronously (ie. piping to an async script doing the `Select` and `Export-CSV`) so that you can grab the next page and trigger the next export without the previous one blocking the main script.

Comment: By _pagination control_ I mean [Simple Paged Results Control](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Simple%20Paged%20Results%20Control)

Comment: Your performance issue is likely not the processor speed but the data transfer, in other words I would run this query separately on each specific domain server.

Comment: As above, querying one domain controller is probably not going to get significantly faster even if you try in parallel. You'd have to send each job to a different domain controller.